# Approximate three or more numbers

Tags: number-theory, approximation, irrational-numbers

I know that using continued fraction I can approximate $$\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2},$$ which means that i can find two integers such that $2^{k_2} \approx 3^{k_3}$, my question is **can I approximate using continued fraction or any other method** three integer $k_2 ,k_3,k_5$ such that $2^{k_2} \approx 3^{k_3} \approx 5^{k_5}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can find infinitely many integers that fulfill your requirement (or, perhaps, none at all, depending on what you mean by "$\approx$").  However, there are likely some constraints that you might wish to impose.  To start, I'm going to rephrase your question slightly, just to make myself more comfortable.

> Suppose that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_n$ are real numbers.  Further suppose that they are mutually incommensurable (i.e. $\frac{a_i}{a_j} \not\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $i\ne j$).  For a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, is there an efficient way to find $Q,p_1,p_2,\dotsc,p_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
>
> 1. $\left|Q\alpha_i - p_i \right| < \varepsilon$, and
> 2. $Q$ is not "very big" (by choosing $Q > \varepsilon^{-1}$, I can find lots of good $p_i$—can we do better?).

That is, can I approximate each of the $\alpha_i$ with rational numbers that all have the same denominator, where that denominator is not too big?

I do not have the expertise to give a complete answer to your question, but let me offer a tentative "yes."  You can first approximate each of the $\alpha_i$ via, say, continued fraction approximation.  You can then find a common denominator via some kind of basis reduction algorithm, such as the LLL algorithm.  This process is outlined in chapter 9 of the text by Bremner, cited below.  Further references are also provided.

*Bremner, Murray R.*, [**Lattice basis reduction. An introduction to the LLL algorithm and its applications**](http://www.crcnetbase.com/isbn/9781439807040), Pure and Applied Mathematics (Boca Raton) 300. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4398-0702-6/hbk; 978-1-4398-0704-0/ebook). xvii, 316 p. (2012). [ZBL1237.68007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1237.68007).

*Kaib, Michael; Schnorr, Claus P.*, [**The generalized Gauss reduction algorithm**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1996.0059), J. Algorithms 21, No. 3, 565-578 (1996). [ZBL0876.68049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0876.68049).

*Lenstra, A.K.; Lenstra, H.W.jun.; Lovász, László*, [**Factoring polynomials with rational coefficients**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01457454), Math. Ann. 261, 515-534 (1982). [ZBL0488.12001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0488.12001).

Comment: Good answer, but could you please provide an algorithm that produces such integers.

Answer (score 5):

$2 = 3^{\log_3 2} = 5^{\log_5 2}$

Set $\log_3 2 = \frac {\ln 2}{\ln 3} \approx \frac pq$ and $\log_5 2 =\frac {\ln 2}{\ln 5} \approx \frac rs$ approximated as closely as you like.

$2^{qs} \approx 3^{ps} \approx 5^{rq}$.

(However the margin of error will be significantly higher.  But you can make the error as small as you like but making the initial error between $\frac pq$ and $\frac rx$ and $\log_3 2$ and $\log_5 2$ exponentially smaller.)

Example $\log_3 2 \approx .63$ and $\log_5 2 \approx .43$

So $2^{100} \approx 3^{63} \approx 5^{43}$

$ 1267650600228229401496703205376\approx 1144561273430837494885949696427 \approx 1136868377216160297393798828125$

Comment: Thanks, just one last thing, can you show me how to do this for four integer or more.

Comment: here are power for which $2^{k_2} \approx 3^{k_3} \approx 5^{k_5} \approx 7^{k_7}$, these are the power for $2$ $\{699,859,1558,2257,8554,10112,10811,14382\}$, which seems that they are common.